# macのterminalを起動がおかしい

Tags: macos

macでterminalを起動すると

```
Last login: Tue Apr 14 11:45:32 on ttys000
-bash: /usr/local/src/ansible/hacking/env-setup: No such file or directory
localhost:~ hogehoge$
```

のように毎回言われてしまいます。
またホスト名もなぜかlocalhostに書き換わってしまっています。
(コンピュータ名は設定していて以前まではちゃんと反映されておりました)

どなたか解決方法ご存じの方はいらっしゃいますでしょうか。

Comment: ~/.bash_profile や ~/.bashrc の内容をご掲載いただけると回答の助けになるかもしれません。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
~/.bash_profile内の
    source /usr/local/src/ansible/hacking/env-setup
これが原因みたいですね。。。

Comment: 'source /usr/local/src/ansible/hacking/env-setup' この部分を消して対応しました。ありがとうございます。
localhostが直らない部分はまだ謎ですが。

Comment: ホスト名のほうは
`sudo scutil --set HostName hoge.local` で直りました。

Comment: 解決した結果を、コメントでは無く投稿して、自己承認してください。それでこの質問が解決した扱いになります。

Answer (score 1):

`~/.bash_profile`内の`source /usr/local/src/ansible/hacking/env-setup`が原因でした。
ホスト名のほうは`sudo scutil --set HostName hoge.local`で直りました。